# View is not working in Android 4.4.4 version kitkat

Tags: android, xml

```
  <LinearLayout   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/operatorLine"
            android:layout_width="180px"
            android:layout_height= "7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="95px"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/adminLine"
            android:layout_width="155px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95px"
            android:layout_height= "7dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have to draw a two lines but view is not working in Android 4.4.4 kitkat version .

Comment: Where else have you tried till now?

Comment: Please explain "is not working".

Answer (score 0):

Use **dp** instead of **px** then check its work.

Comment: then change your background color.

Answer (score 0):

If your background color is white then you will not see it because it is same in operatorLine and adminLine
Try with

```
  <View
        android:id="@+id/operatorLine"
        android:layout_width="180px"
        android:layout_height= "7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="95px"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/adminLine"
        android:layout_width="155px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95px"
        android:layout_height= "7dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the colour, and see the result , as #ffffff is white and your background is also white, so it's not visible, try some other colour code , and that too different for both lines

Answer (score 0):

Use this code will show you your views

```
<LinearLayout   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/operatorLine"
            android:layout_width="180px"
            android:layout_height= "7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="95px"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/adminLine"
            android:layout_width="155px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95px"
            android:layout_height= "7dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working ,I have changed dp as sp , I do not know why but now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of View you can also user other views like LinearLayout,RelativeLayout because all these also one type of view.

## I have to draw a two lines but view is not working in Android 4.4.4 kitkat version .

Here,Issue not with dp ,sp or px.

User below code so you can see your view

```
<LinearLayout   
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/operatorLine"
            android:layout_width="180px"
            android:layout_height= "7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="95px"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/adminLine"
            android:layout_width="155px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95px"
            android:layout_height= "7dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>
```